# Laravel split in blade template nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, split, laravel-blade

I retrieve an array of IDs separated by white space as shown below

```
  @foreach($user_notify->user_notify_divisions as $user_notify)
                    {{$user_notify}}
  @endforeach
```

Then the value of $user_notify will be the ID

```
   $user_notify = 2 3 4 5
```

I have a database table **division_list**

```
            id        division_name
             1         工業製品卸・小売
             2         繊維・衣料製造
             3         繊維・衣料卸・小売
             4         食品製造
             5         食品卸・小売
             6         医薬品製造
```

Now how to get division_name with the above id string

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `laravel` `blade templating` you can do it like this `nested foreach`.

Another problem in your code is, you are iterating on `$user_notify->user_notify_divisions` and defining value as `$user_notify` you should have different variable name instead of same name as of object

```
@foreach($user_notify->user_notify_divisions as $user_notify)
                    {{$user_notify}}
@endforeach
```

**Corrected code:**

```
@foreach($user_notify->user_notify_divisions as $user_data)
    @foreach(explode(" ",$user_data) as $ids)
          {{$ids}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I hope so! Let me test, tks you!

Comment: I did it, thank you very much! And can you help me with this one again? @Sahil Gulati

Comment: $user_career = Career::find($id)
@Sahil Gulati Can you help me out here, if I pass $ user_career with a view it works
`return view('user.user_confirm',['user_career'=>$user_career])`
But I want to use redirect, it does not work
`return redirect('users/registration/confirm')->with('user_career',$user_career)`
Now how to transfer data?

Comment: @HoàngTrần Try this `Route::get('user/profile', ['as' => 'profile', function ($category,$id) {

}]);
 
return redirect()->route('profile', ['category'=>513, 'id'=>1]);` first define a route like this and redirect with data

Answer (score 1):

you can use `explode()` to split the string.

```
$arr = explode(' ', $user_notify);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode`
or
directly access by id.

```
$id_array = [2,3,4,5];
dd($id_array[0]); // results 2
```